# Make textarea appear if option selected

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have the following code:

```
<form name="input" action="<?php echo URL; ?>jc/write_upaction" method="post" id="derp">
    <label><span style='font-weight: bold;'>Name(s):<input style='width:30%;' type="text" placeholder="Name, Name" name="name" required></span>
    </label>
    <label><span style='font-weight: bold;'>Date:<input style='width:30%;' type="date" placeholder="MM/DD/YYYY" name="date" required></span>
    </label>
    <label for="date"><span style='font-weight: bold;'>Time:<input style='width:30%;' type="time" placeholder="HH:MM" name="time" required></span>
    </label>
    <label for="time"><span style='font-weight: bold;'>Witnesses:<input style='width:30%;' type="text" placeholder="Name, Name" name="witnesses"></span>
    </label>
    <label><span style='font-weight: bold;'>Reason:</span>
    </label>
    <select name="reason" style="width:30%;">
        <option value="placeholder">Didn't clean up mess</option>
        <option value="Other">Other, Specify below</option>
    </select>
    </label>
    <textarea form="input" id="txtarea" placeholder="Write your reason here..." name="reason_other" cols="28" rows="5"></textarea>
    <div style="text-align:right;"><span style="font-weight:bold;" id="counter"></span>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

I would like the option valued "Other" too make the textarea  name'd "reason_other" appear if the option Other is selected. Is there anyway to do this?

Comment: Kidding aside, yes it can be done, but StackOverflow isn't a code generation service. The volunteers on this site are here to help troubleshoot specific problems. What jQuery code have you tried? I'd suggest starting with the docs for `change()` and `show()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/fenderistic/6ejps/

Just give your select element an id of whatever, in this case, I set it to be `slct`.

```
$("#txtarea").hide();

$( "#slct" ).change(function() {
   var val = $("#slct").val();
if(val=="Other"){
    $("#txtarea").show();
} else {
    $("#txtarea").hide();
}
});
```

Comment: Worked great, just had to move my script tag below the elements, haha. Thanks once again! I have been stumped by this for hours.

Comment: @RainbowDashDC , Your script tag could be above if you wrap the above code with `$( document ).ready(function() {//put code in here });` so the script won't run until the page has been loaded. It's very common and good practice to do so.

Answer (score 1):

With this:

```
$(function(){
  $("select[name=reason]").change(function(){
      if($(this).val() == 'Other')
          $('#txtarea').show();
      else
          $('#txtarea').hide();
  });
});
```

Cheers

Comment: This _only_ makes it hide **if** a value has been changed. It's not hidden at first.

Answer (score 1):

with jquery yes :

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$("select").change(function(){
val = $(this).val();
if(val == "Other")
{
$("#txtarea").show();
}
});

});
```

add this in your css

```
#txtarea {display:none;}
```

Answer (score 0):

using Jquery the change option would work well:

http://api.jquery.com/change/

Answer (score 0):

toggle the visibilty based on the selects value

```
$('[name="reason"]').on('change', function() {
     $('#txtarea').toggle(this.value == 'Other');
}).trigger('change');
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/zbRF2/2/)

Without jQuery

```
var select   = document.getElementsByName('reason')[0],
    textarea = document.getElementById('txtarea');

if (select.addEventListener) {
     select.addEventListener('change', handler, false);
} else if (select.attachEvent) {
     select.attachEvent('onchange', handler);
}

function handler() {
    textarea.style.display = this.value == 'Other' ? 'inline' : 'none';
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/zbRF2/3/)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution without any jQuery:

Try this, add an "onchange" to your :

```
<select name="reason" style="width:30%;" onchange="reasonChanged(this);">
```

The function reasonChanged(....) will be called whenever that select's value is changed, and the "this", passes a reference to that DOM node that called the function.

Define the function as:

```
function reasonChanged(select_obj) {
  var textArea = document.querySelector("#txtarea");
  if (select_obj.value == "Other") {
    textArea.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    textArea.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

I haven't tested this, so you'll have to test it and debug it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

```
**Here is solution please try it.......**

<script>
function showhide(){ alert(document.getElementById('reason').value);
if(document.getElementById('reason').value == 'Other'){
document.getElementById('txtarea').style.display = 'block';
}
else{
document.getElementById('txtarea').style.display = 'none';
}
}
</script>
<form>
<label><span style='font-weight: bold;'>Reason:</span>
    </label>
    <select id="reason" name="reason" style="width:30%;" onchange="javascript: showhide();">
        <option value="placeholder">Didn't clean up mess</option>
        <option value="Other">Other, Specify below</option>
    </select>
    </label>
    <textarea  style="display:none;" form="input" id="txtarea" placeholder="Write your reason here..." name="reason_other" cols="28" rows="5"></textarea>
 </form>
```